# Solving $a^5=a^3bc+b^2c$ in integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solving $a^5=a^3bc+b^2c$ in integers.

I tried assuming there is a common divisor first of a,b,c, then a,b and 2 other pairs, but not sure how to arrive to a contradiction, trying some things right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$cb^2+a^3cb-a^5=0 \Rightarrow a^6c^2+4a^5c$ is a square number,
so $a^2c^2+4ac$ should be square number.

Comment: Yes, that's then a necessary condition. Does it lead to a contradiction?

Comment: @coffeemath that makes $a^2c^2+4ac$ and $(ac+2)^2$ two perfect squares with difference $4$, we know there are only a finitely many pairs of perfect squares that differ by $4$ :-)

Comment: this is brilliant!  :)how come i didn't notice the quadratic trinomial

Comment: @r9m I see your comment, and checked -- the squares would have to be $0,4$ and no solution. (+1 on comment, and on Belanov's answer.)